# Изменить класс white на black в "select" js или jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть select с 2 значениями white и black.

Нужно изменить значение класса white на класс black и обратно на white в зависимости от выбора. На всех Div

```
<select id="sel" name="sel" class="theme">
  <option value="white">white</option>
  <option value="black">black</option>
</select>

<div class='white'> main
    <div class='white'> content1 </div>
    <div class='white'> content2 </div>
```

JavaScript или JQuery

Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: Our working language is Russian. Therefore please translate your question into Russian or move it to [intl. SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Спасибо перепутал, сейчас напишу на русском

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#sel").change(function(){
  $("div").removeClass("white black").addClass($(this).val());
});
$("#sel").change();
```

```css
.white{ color:red; }
.black{ color:green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel" name="sel" class="theme">
  <option value="white">white</option>
  <option value="black">black</option>
</select>

<div> main </div>
<div> content1 </div>
<div> content2 </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это как раз то что нужно. Все гениальное просто. А то сам не мог сообразить как с select такое сделать.

Comment: @PavelTk Пожалуйста. Успехов! Галочка слева - щёлк :).

Comment: Спасибо за галочку, тоже не мог понять как отметить ваш код. :)))))

Answer (score 2):

```css
.white{
  color:red;
}
.black{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<select name="sel" class="theme" onchange="sel.className = this.value">
  <option value="white">white</option>
  <option value="black">black</option>
</select>

<div id="sel" class='white'> content </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я немного поменял вопрос, просто мне нужно менять не на одном Div а на нескольких.